# When running the code I am getting 100.789 to remove the last 100.789 from the output what should I do without touching the rest of the code?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Flower:
    def __init__(self, name, petals, price):
        self.name = name

        try:
            petals = int(petals)
        except:
            print("There is an error.")
        self.petals = petals

        try:
            price = float(price)
        except:
            print("There is an error.")
        self.price = price

    def get_name(self):
        if self.name is None:
            return ('No Attribute')
        else:
            return self.name

    def get_petals(self):
        if self.petals is None:
            return ('No Attribute')
        else:
            return self.petals

    def get_price(self):
        if self.price is None:
            return ('No Attribute')
        else:
            return self.price

flower1= Flower('Rose','100.798','100')
print(flower1.petals)
```

Comment: When you instantiate Flower you give the value `'100.798'` to `petals`, so it's normal that when you do `print(flower1.petals)` it prints `100.798`

Comment: But I want to print it only if its an integer and raise error if its not

Answer (score 0):

When an Exception occurs, you need to do something to control what value gets assigned to the corresponding instance attribute (`self.petals` or `self.price`). This shows what I mean:

```
class Flower:
    def __init__(self, name, petals, price):
        self.name = name

        try:
            petals = int(petals)
        except ValueError:
            print("There is an error:")
            petals = ''
        self.petals = petals

        try:
            price = float(price)
        except ValueError:
            print("There is an error:")
            price = ''
        self.price = price

    def get_name(self):
        if self.name is None:
            return ('No Attribute')
        else:
            return self.name

    def get_petals(self):
        if self.petals is None:
            return ('No Attribute')
        else:
            return self.petals

    def get_price(self):
        if self.price is None:
            return ('No Attribute')
        else:
            return self.price

flower1= Flower('Rose','100.798','100')
print(flower1.petals)
```

Comment: No but still it's showing 0 I want to remove that too

Comment: Then set the value to the empty string instead of `0`: i.e. `petals = ''`

Comment: Yes thanks it seems to work now